# TFS: Find Files Affected Between Changesets

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, tfs

We are using Team Foundation Server 2012.

We had a guy submit 97 files (not counting the designer and resource files) in Changeset 13646 on 8/9/2016.

Ten (10) days later on 8/18/2016, he rolled these changes back in Changeset 13716.

During that time, other work items were submitted and completed.

Is there some way to query TFS to find the **Filenames** and **WorkItems** that were included in any Changeset between 13646 and 13716?

I would like this to be an SQL query that I can run in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though this is for TFS 2013 I'm hopeful it works in 2012. This was run against the tfs_warehouse database

```
 SELECT DISTINCT df.[FileName]
    ,df.FilePath
    ,dcs.ChangesetID AS 'ChangeSetID'
    ,dwi.System_id AS 'WorkItemID'
    ,dwi.System_WorkItemType
    ,dwi.System_State
    ,dwi.System_CreatedDate
    ,dwi.System_ChangedDate

FROM DimFile df 
JOIN FactCodeChurn fcc ON df.FileSK = fcc.FilenameSK
JOIN FactWorkItemChangeset fwi ON fcc.ChangesetSK = fwi.ChangesetSK
JOIN DimWorkItem dwi ON fwi.WorkItemID = dwi.System_id
AND fwi.TeamProjectCollectionSK = dwi.TeamProjectCollectionSK
AND fwi.RemovedDateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, N'9999', 126)
JOIN DimChangeset dcs ON dcs.ChangesetSK = fcc.ChangesetSK 

WHERE dcs.ChangesetID BETWEEN 13646 AND 13716

ORDER BY dcs.ChangesetID
```

The file path does also have the filename within it, but I thought I would include the filename as a separate field

Comment: If I wanted to get better at doing this sort of thing, how do I go about it? Is there a site that offers a lot of TFS SQL information? The query works, but I wouldn't know how to build on it or modify it for use later.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not come across a site dedicated to that sort of thing. I have picked it up myself by the odd snippet around the web e.g. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/report/sql-reports/work-item-link-history-tables and https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/report/sql-reports/table-reference-relational-warehouse-database These links are for TFS 2013 upwards but hopefully they are mostly relevant to 2012

Comment: you also have the existing reports you can use https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/report/sql-reports/perspective-test-analyze-report-work and if your comfortable with SQL Profiler you can use that to pick out the tsql used

Answer (score 6):

There is also a way to do this with a SQL query using the Relational data warehouse. You will need access to the `tfs_warehouse` database for this. There are a few dimension tables you must join to get what you need:

- [dbo.WorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244668(v=vs.90).aspx#WorkItem)
- [dbo.WorkItemChangeset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244668(v=vs.90).aspx#Changeset)
- [dbo.ChangeSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244703(v=vs.90).aspx#Changeset)
- [dbo.CodeChurn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244703(v=vs.90).aspx#CodeChurn)
- [dbo.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244703(v=vs.90).aspx#File)

You can use `dbo.WorkItemChangeset` for the link between changesets and work items and `dbo.CodeChurn` for the link between changesets and files.

The documentation on this is old and incomplete, but here are some links that explain the fact and dimension tables:

- [Understanding the Data Warehouse Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244687(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [relational schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244691(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [work items schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244668(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [source control schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244703(v=vs.90).aspx)

Note that their is only one `Tfs_Warehouse` database so the information of all projects in all project collections is stored here. Therefore you **cannot** trust changeset or work items ID's to be unique. These values are unique within a single project collection so in the `Tfs_Warehouse` the combination of project collection and changeset or workitem ID is unique.

*Unfortunately I do not have access to a `Tfs_Warehouse` database at the moment so I'm unable to provide you with the exact query. But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157683/number-of-workitems-with-changesets-or-linked-items-with-changesets) has a similar query you could modify.*

Comment: This looks like exactly what I've been trying to find. I'm exploring the query in the linked question you posted. There might be a way to modify it to return for me what I'm after.

Comment: Congratulations.

Answer (score 4):

`tf history` command with **/format:Detailed** parameter cannot display related work items, which won't meet your requirement.

It's not suggest to query database directly. Instead, you can use [tf changeset](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/changeset-command) command to display full information, which will include changed items and related work items:

```
tf changeset changesetnumber /noprompt /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl
```

In your case, you need to run two commands like:

```
tf changeset 13646 /noprompt /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl
tf changeset 13716 /noprompt /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl
```

Check my example in following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I answered the exact same thing 5 days back :)

Comment: but looks like he prefers using SQL query directly

Answer (score 3):

The below command will return the list of files modified, along with the check-in comments, and I think you should see the work items as well (but I havent tested that part) into a log file. Please update the collection url, branch name in the below command.

```
tf history /collection:"tfsserverurl/collection" $/TFSbranchName /noprompt /recursive /format:detailed /v:C13646~C13716 > changeset.log
```

Example:

> Changeset: 13646 User: LastName, FirstName Date: Thursday, February
>   16, 2017 4:26:50 PM
>
> Comment:  Added values/code back missed from December branch code
>   merge
>
> Items:   edit $/TFSBranchName/abc.cs
>
> Check-in Notes:   Code Reviewer:   Performance Reviewer:   Security
>   Reviewer:

If you copy all the "Items" from the log file (changeset.log) you should get all the files that were modified in those changsesets.

Comment: Is that run from the command line (not some TFS web interface console or SMS window)?

Comment: Run that from the VS developer command prompt. For example, VS 2013 it will be in the below location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts\Developer Command Prompt for VS2013

Comment: Can the `/collection` parameter be a remote location? The url in our TFS browser is `w2000-dev:8080/tfs/CORE/Win/`. I can navigate to our **w2000-dev** PC on our network `\\w2000-dev\`, but the **tf** command keeps giving me "No URL can be found that corresponds to the following server name".

Comment: nope, thats your web portal url. Go to VS -> Team explorer pane -> you should see this in the home. Or click on the "connect" button (plug icon). If you are already connected you should get the server URL there.

Comment: Were you able to get the TFS server url? Did the command work?

Comment: No, I spent some time on it again this morning, but I wasn't able to find what you were talking about.

Comment: Open Visual Studio -> Team -> Manage Connections. Then on the team explorer pane -> Manage Connections -> Connect to team project. Now click on the server button and that should give yout the URL for your current repository.

Comment: Well, that's different. This time I got a message saying I don't have access. It would be nice to make what I want into a stored procedure that I could keep on the server.

Comment: Thats strange, can you open the branch in visual studio -> source control explorer . Right click and check view history? This is a basic command and doesnt require any special rights to run.

Comment: Yes, I can see all of that. I'm not sure what to put for a branch name up where you have `$/TFSbranchName`. Our TFS administrator does not let us do branches. I tried `Core/Win` and `DefaultCollection` (from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands)), but I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: TFSBranch is the folder name where you check-in your code in TFS. It takes the format $TFSprojectName/Foldername.

Comment: No, I can't get that to work at all. So far, **kevchadders** answer works. I would mark his as the answer right now, but I really wished he would explain his answer some.

Comment: I can also save/export **kevchadders** answer to a CSV/Excel file to send in to management.